# Polymorphic call to virtual functions with varying number of arguments

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism

Is it possible to achieve behaviour demonstrated below with virtual functions? 
 And if it's not the correct way to go about polymorphism then what would be the correct way in this example?

```
class Base_
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
public:
    Base_(float xx=0, float yy=0, float zz=0)
    {
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
        z = zz;
    }
   virtual void SetParemeters(what here?)=0; //Different number of arguments 
};

class Derived_1 :public Base_
{
    float r;
public:
    Derived_1(float rr=1, float xx=0, float yy=0, float zz=0):Base_(xx,yy,zz)
    {
        r=rr;
    }
    virtual void SetParemeters(float v1) //Different number of arguments
    {
        r=v1;
    }
};

class Derived_2 :public Base_
{
    float k;
    float w;
public:
    Derived_2(float kk=1, float ww=1,float xx=0, float yy=0, float zz=0):Base_(xx,yy,zz)
    {
        k=kk;
        w=ww;
    }
    virtual void SetParemeters(float v1, float v2) //Different number of arguments
    {
        k=v1;
        w=v2;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived_1 d1;
    Derived_2 d2;
    Base_ *ptr;

    ptr = &d1;
    ptr -> SetParemeters(one argument)

    ptr = &d2;
    ptr-> SetParemeters(one or two arguments) 

    return 0;
}
```

And even if I managed to achieve that, how can I set only second parameter (k) here:
 `ptr-> SetParemeters(one or two arguments)`?

I searched for answers but I only found answers to specific scenarios which made the whole thing difficult for me to understand.

Comment: I don't think polymorphy is the right tool here. See [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-3-liskov-substitution-interface-segregation-principles--net-36710). What would you expect to happen if I called `ptr->SetParameters(1, 2)` while `ptr` points to a `Derived_2`? (PS: It's par**a**meters, not par**e**meters.).

Comment: @MaxLanghof After I create object with some values `Derived_2 d1(3,5)` When `ptr` points to `Derived_2` and I call `ptr->SetParameters(1, 2)` I want to get `k=1` and `w=2`, if I call `ptr->SetParameters(1)` I want `k=1` and `w=5`. And when `ptr` points to  `Derived_1`  I want to pass one argument, if more than one argument is passed I want to display an error.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I meant "while `ptr` points to a `Derived_1`". In other words, what do you expect to happen when calling the wrong function for the actual run-time type?

Comment: If `ptr` points to `Derived_1` and I call `SetParameters()` with two arguments I'd like to catch an error just as I would if I were to call `SetParameters()` with three arguments when `ptr` points to `Derived_2`. Could you elaborate on run-time type in thix context?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make `Base_::SetParameters` takes two (optional) arguments:

```
class Base_
{
// [...]
public:
   virtual void SetParemeters(float=0f, float=0f)=0;
};
```

`Derived_1::SetParameters` just ignores the first one:

```
class Derived_1 :public Base_
{
    // [...]
    virtual void SetParemeters(float v1, float=0f)
    {
        r=v1;
    }
};
```

while `Derived_2` takes the both of them

```
class Derived_2 :public Base_
{
    // [...]
    virtual void SetParemeters(float v1, float v2)
    {
        k=v1;
        w=v2;
    }
};
```

demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c528ffff005df5b9

Note though, this significantly reduces the interest of virtual functions...

Comment: I considered this approach however when it comes to Derived_2 the second value is set to 0 if I pass only one argument. So when I do 
    Derived_2 d2(7,7); 
    Base_ *ptr;
    ptr = &d2;
    ptr -> SetParemeters(2);
I get
    k=2 w=0
Instead of
    k=2 w=7

Answer (score 0):

```
Derived_1 d1;
Derived_2 d2;
Base_ *ptr;

ptr = &d1;
ptr->SetParameters(one argument)

ptr = &d2;
ptr->SetParameters(one or two arguments)
```

The way how this code is written implies that you have knowledge about two things:

- at the time of the first call to `SetParameters()`, `ptr` points to an object of type `Derived_1`
- at the second call, it points to an object of type `Derived_2`.

This in turn means that you know the static types -- and in fact, you *need to*, due to the different signatures.

For such a scenario, dynamic polymorphism is not the right choice, because its premise is that you can talk to different implementations (overridden methods) using a **uniform access** (calling the virtual base method).

So, if you have this knowledge at compile time, simply use non-virtual method calls.

---

However, there are similar scenarios where you may actually be interested in supporting different signatures *at runtime*, for example if you load configuration dynamically. Here is an example, where not the *number*, but the *types* of arguments differ.

```
class Car : public Vehicle
{
    virtual void addFuel(const Petrol& f) override;
};

class Airplane : public Vehicle
{
    virtual void addFuel(const Kerosene& f) override;
};
```

How would then the base function look?

```
class Vehicle
{ 
    virtual ~Vehicle() {} // don't forget this!
    virtual void addFuel(const /* which type? */& f) = 0;
};
```

One option is to make the fuel type a hierarchy as well (both `Kerosene` and `Petrol` inherit the `Fuel` class):

```
class Vehicle
{ 
    virtual ~Vehicle() {}
    virtual void addFuel(const Fuel& f) = 0;
};
```

However, in this case, each implementation would need to either rely on the fact it's passed the right fuel, or check the type at runtime.

```
class Airplane : public Vehicle
{
    virtual void addFuel(const Fuel& f) override
    {
        if (auto* k = dynamic_cast<const Kerosene*>(&f))
        {
            // use concrete fuel
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `SetParameters` a variadic function and have the polymorphic interface be internal, providing the writeable parameters in a generic form (here as a vector of pointers to them):

```
class Base_
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
public:
    Base_(float xx=0, float yy=0, float zz=0)
    {
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
        z = zz;
    }

    virtual std::vector<float*> getAllExtraParameters() = 0;

    template<class ... Ts>
    void SetExtraParameters(Ts&& ... ts)
    {
        auto extras = getAllExtraParameters();
        if (sizeof...(ts) > extras.size())
          throw std::runtime_error("Too many parameters given!");

        // Fold expression - could be implemented differently in C++ < 17.
        int index = 0;
        ((*extras[index++] = ts), ...);
    }
};


class Derived_1 :public Base_
{
    float r;
public:
    Derived_1(float rr=1, float xx=0, float yy=0, float zz=0):Base_(xx,yy,zz)
    {
        r=rr;
    }

    std::vector<float*> getAllExtraParameters() override
    {
        return { &r };
    }
};

class Derived_2 :public Base_
{
public:
    float k;
    float w;

    Derived_2(float kk=1, float ww=1,float xx=0, float yy=0, float zz=0):Base_(xx,yy,zz)
    {
        k=kk;
        w=ww;
    }

    std::vector<float*> getAllExtraParameters() override
    {
        return { &k, &w };
    }
};
```

Demo and tests: https://godbolt.org/z/ofXnuH